# Redirecionamento de requisições HTTP

Tags: php, htaccess, redirecionamento

Estou com o seguinte problema: gostaria de redirecionar (por meio do .htaccess) as urls abaixo com redirecionamento temporário (`HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily`)

Exemplos:

- `http://www.site.com.br/artigo/0/` para `http://www.site.com.br/artigo/1/`
- `http://www.site.com.br/artigo/2/` para `http://www.site.com.br/artigo/1/`
- `http://www.site.com.br/artigo/3/` para `http://www.site.com.br/artigo/1/`
- etc.

Pe

Answer (score 1):

Adicione ao seu .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^/?artigo/[023]$ /artigo/1 [R=302,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode Utilizar está regra:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#regra de redirecionamento de urls antigas
redirectMatch 302 ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com.br/artigo/1/
</IfModule>
```

Você redirecionará todas páginas para o mesmo lugar.

Créditos para Segio Ronei em [Redirecionamento 301 e 302](http://www.sergioronei.com.br/seo/redirecionamento-301-302-site-htaccess)

**V2:** para somente os artigos você pode alterar a **Expressão Regular** para **^(artigo\/*)$**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#regra de redirecionamento de urls antigas
redirectMatch 302 ^(artigo\/*)$ http://www.site.com.br/artigo/1/
</IfModule>
```

assim todos URLs que contiver http://www.site.com.br/artigo/ serão redirecionadas.

Comment: Só um detalhe: s/302/301

Comment: Na verdade a ideia era adicionar apenas para os artigos. Isso vai redirecionar o site todo.